# QRTEngine - Hiding Init and Exit questions

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am using QRTEngine in qualtrics. I have a problem with hiding the Init and the Exit part, here is what I have tried to do so far:

```js
Init:

QRTE.Init({
// should correspond with Embedded Data field names
blockData: ‘${e://Field/QRTE_blockData}’,
idData: ‘${e://Field/QRTE_idData}’,
columnData: ‘${e://Field/QRTE_columns}’,
exitQuestions: ‘${e://Field/QRTE_exitQuestions}’,
exitItemTag: ‘ExitQ’, // DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE FOR NEW BLOCKS
blockId: ‘Deafult Question Block’, // DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE FOR NEW BLOCKS
onLoadFn: function() {
// set trial configuration for the screens
QRTE.setConfig(‘Smiley’, ‘duration’, 2000);
QRTE.setConfig(‘StroopItem’, ‘duration’, 6000);
QRTE.setConfig(‘StroopItem’, ‘allowable’, ‘xm’);
QRTE.setConfig(‘StroopItem’, ‘EndAction’, ‘TERMINATE’);
// save trial configurations for later analysis
QRTE.setTrialData(‘StimulusSimely’, ‘${lm://Field/1}’);
QRTE.setTrialData(‘Piconright’, ‘${lm://Field/2}’);
QRTE.setTrialData(‘Piconleft’, ‘${lm://Field/3}’);
this.questionContainer.style.display = ‘none';
},
interTrialDelay: [1000] // set interTrialDelay
});
onLoadFn: (function()
{
this.questionContainer.style.display = ‘none';
});

Exit:

QRTE.Exit();
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
this.questionContainer.style.display = ‘none';
});
```

My goal would be to prevent the engine from displaying these questions.
I have tried to set the intertrialdelay to 0, but in that case the whole experiment became a mess.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you posted this question on the QRTEngine forums?

Comment: Does your code really have single opening and closing quotes instead of apostrophes?  If so, that's a problem...especially the mismatched quotes on the display='none' lines as it relates to your problem.